# How do I route GCM messages from a GcmListenerService to their relevant handlers?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

The app that I am working on has two services (Pushwoosh and Helpshift) that use GCM for push notifications. I am attempting to implement the functionality shown here, in the Pushwoosh documentation, to allow both systems to function; https://docs.pushwoosh.com/v1.0/docs/gcm-integration-legacy. However my Android knowledge is failing me for how I actually route the bundle recieved to the relevant handlers. The project is dones in Unity but this is very much Android territory.

Here is the `GcmListenerService` class I have created that is very similar to the example;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.*;
import android.content.ComponentName;

public class GCMListenerRouterService extends GcmListenerService
{
    public GCMListenerRouterService()
    {
        super();
        Log.i("Unity", "GCMListener - Constuctor");
    }

    private void dispatchMessage(String component, Bundle data)
    {
        Log.i("Unity", "GCMListener - dispatchMessage: " + (data != null ? data.toString() : "<null>") + " component: " + component);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtras(data);
        intent.setAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), component));

        GcmReceiver.startWakefulService(getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data)
    {
        Log.i("Unity", "GCMListener - onMessageReceived: " + (data != null ? data.toString() : "<null>") + " from: " + from);

        // Base GCM listener service removes this extra before calling onMessageReceived
        // Need to set it again to pass intent to another service
        //data.putString("from", from);

        //if (TextUtils.equals(from, getString(R.string.PUSHWOOSH_PROJECT_ID)))
        //{
        //    dispatchMessage(PushGcmIntentService.class.getName(), data);
        //}
        //else if (TextUtils.equals(from, getString(R.string.PRIVATE_PROJECT_ID)))
        //{
        //    dispatchMessage(PrivateGCMListenerService.class.getName(), data);
        //}
    }
}
```

I am able to confirm that the push notification came from the correct messaging service, and I can determine if a push notifications came from one plugin or another. How do I route these bundle objects to the correct handler? I do not understand the following sample code;

```
if (TextUtils.equals(from, getString(R.string.PUSHWOOSH_PROJECT_ID)))
{
    dispatchMessage(PushGcmIntentService.class.getName(), data);
}
else if (TextUtils.equals(from, getString(R.string.PRIVATE_PROJECT_ID)))
{
    dispatchMessage(PrivateGCMListenerService.class.getName(), data);
}
```

I appreciate that this is example code but I can't find any functions in the Android documentation with the same signature as `dispatchMessage`. Do I need to make an intent service for each different type of message that is needed?

I know that for Helpshift I need to call a function with the signature `handlePush(Context context, Bundle data)` but I'm not sure what the `Context` object is. For Pushwoosh, i'm not sure what the handler is. While I am talking about two particular services I am assuming that this setup is a standard method for receiving messages and handling them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that, for that for GCM, `Bundle` objects are the raw push details that you need to be handled. No further processing is needed and plugins/frameworks that support GCM should have a function that handles this, e.g. For helpshift that function is in `com.helpshift.Core` called `handlePush(Context context, Bundle data)`.

Note that GCM is actually deprecated and Firebase Cloud Messenger is the new system going forward. This service has a different way of dealing with multiple push handlers and you should check your plugins for documentation on this.